# How to create Mock(Moq) object of ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>

Tags: .net-core, moq, identityserver4

Can somebody explain, how I can create a Mock object of a class that extends `ApiAuthorizationDbContext<IdentityUser>` ?

The class `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ApiAuthorizationDbContext<IdentityUser>`
is from this nuget: Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer .

Sample:

```
public class AppDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<IdentityUser>
{       
      
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options, IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions)
            : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
        {            
        }
}
```

I am using Moq.
The Tutorial I followed expects to have a DbContext with a parameterless constructor which is not Possible in my case, because `ApiAuthorizationDbContext<IdentityUser>` has no parameterless constructor.

Comment: Don't mock `DbContext`, instead use different providers, for example `In-Memory` or `Sqlite` with in-memory option.

Comment: I've used the in-mem provider for just this purpose and it works well